# Error 400 with Client Credentials Flow

Tags: java, spotify

I'm trying to Client Credentials Flow authenticate but keep returning error 400. I've taken a look at the available APIs but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. If somebody could give me a nudge in the right direction that would be fantastic. Thanks

```
package com.elliott.lyric.io;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP.USER_AGENT;

/**
 * Created by elliott on 05/05/2017.
 */
public class SpotifyLoader {

    String nowPlayingURL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing";
    String authURL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials";
    String clientID = "";
    String secretID = "";
    String authScope = "user-read-currently-playing user-read-playback-state";

    public SpotifyLoader() {
        authorize();
        //getRawPlaying();
    }

    void authorize() {
        try {

            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            System.out.println(authURL);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(authURL);

// add header
            post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
            String idSecret = clientID + ":" + secretID;
            String idSecretEncoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(idSecret.getBytes()));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "Basic " + idSecretEncoded));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response Code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    void getRawPlaying() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the request with below changes

1. Move the query string from url to request body so the URL is `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`
2. send authorization in header. I just modified the `authorize()` as below.

   ```
   void authorize() {
   try {

       authURL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
       String idSecret = clientID + ":" + secretID;
       String idSecretEncoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(idSecret.getBytes()));

       HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
       HttpPost post = new HttpPost(authURL);

       post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
       post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + idSecretEncoded);

       List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
       urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));

       post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

       HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
       System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

       StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
       String line = "";
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           result.append(line);
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Thank you so much man. So the I had the auth in the wrong place and misunderstood the parameter section.
So it was doing like ?Authorization=Basic.. etc in the URL?

Comment: You were trying with `Authorization` as form data and `grant_type` as query parameter. :)